# Lucene use taxonomy and DocValues facets together

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, lucene, taxonomy, facet

There are many examples of the use of facets based on the taxonomy index and on  DocValues. But I need use as a hierarchy of categories (taxonomy) and Range queries (NumericDocValuesField) together.
For example DrillSideways :

```
  DrillSideways ds = new DrillSideways (searcher, config, taxoReader);
  DrillSideways.DrillSidewaysResult result = ds.search (q, topScoreDocCollector);
```

The second parameter of **ds.search()** is **TopScoreDocCollector**.

**FacetsCollector** created inside **ds.search()** and not possible to pass this collector to **ds.search()**. Pass **MultiCollector.wrap (FacetsCollector, TopScoreDocCollector)** as second parameter in **ds.search()** is not correct(?). However **FacetsCollector** need to build facets that are not available in the taxonomy index:

```
 Facets facetsTime = new LongRangeFacetCounts (..., FacetsCollector, ...);
 facetsTime.getTopChildren (...);
```

Also list **result.facets** contain null value, which refers to **DocValues** ​​facet.

Maybe you have a working example how use **taxonomy** and **DocValues** ​​facets in **DrillSideways** together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DrillSideways` assumes that you use either TaxonomyFacets or SortedSetDocValuesFacets exclusively. If this is not the case, you can subclass DrillSideways and override the `buildFacetsResult` method to build the final Facets however you like. You will get the FacetsCollector for the DrillDownQuery and two arrays with the sideways FacetCollectors and dims, for every dim you have added to the DrissSideways.

Here is an example:

```
public class MyDrillSideways extends DrillSideways {

  public MyDrillSideways(IndexSearcher searcher, FacetsConfig config, TaxonomyReader taxoReader) {
    super(searcher, config, taxoReader);
  }

  @Override
  protected Facets buildFacetsResult(FacetsCollector drillDowns, FacetsCollector[] drillSideways, String[] drillSidewaysDims) throws IOException {

    String longRangeFacetDim = "mySpecialLongRangeDim";
    Facets drillDownFacets = new FastTaxonomyFacetCounts(taxoReader, config, drillDowns);

    boolean foundLongRangeInDrillSideways = false;
    Map<String, Facets> drillSidewaysFacets = new HashMap<>();
    if (drillSideways != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < drillSideways.length; i++) {
        String sidewaysDim = drillSidewaysDims[i];
        FacetsCollector drillSideway = drillSideways[i];

        Facets sidewaysFacets;
        if (sidewaysDim.equals(longRangeFacetDim)) {
          foundLongRangeInDrillSideways = true;
          sidewaysFacets = new LongRangeFacetCounts(...,drillSideway,...);
        } else {
          sidewaysFacets = new FastTaxonomyFacetCounts(taxoReader, config, drillSideway);
        }
        drillSidewaysFacets.put(sidewaysDim, sidewaysFacets);
      }
    }

    if (!foundLongRangeInDrillSideways) {
      Facets facetsTime = new LongRangeFacetCounts(..., FacetsCollector, ...);
      drillSidewaysFacets.put(longRangeFacetDim, facetsTime);
    }

    return new MultiFacets(drillSidewaysFacets, drillDownFacets);
  }
}
```